# I'm looking for a science fiction short story about freeloading

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a scifi short story in an anthology years ago, in which a ship landed on a planet in which all the citizens traded services for other services, and there were a few people who went around collecting all sorts of free goods and labour but were found out and cast out from society. There was someone on the ship who had a bicycle and needed it fixed, I think?

It was quite a while ago, apologies for not having more details.

Comment: I'm sure you're thinking of "...And Then There Were None" by Eric Frank Russell. One of the spacemen has a bicycle; I don't remember if it needed repairs. Does "planting an ob" ring any bells? I will post a full answer with links after I find my copy.

Comment: @user14111 It does indeed. I found it before I saw this comment, but I appreciate it all the same. Thank you so much!

Comment: Part of a fix-up novel called "The Great Explosion".  Get the whole thing.

Comment: Was about to suggest the same title. Great story. Thanks for suggesting that novel, @EmsleyWyatt, I'd never heard of it before.

Answer (score 10):

I found it, sorry, it's "...And Then There Were None" by Eric Frank Russell. Link [here](https://www.abelard.org/e-f-russell.php).

Comment: The site you linked to hurts my eyes. You can also read it at https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v47n04_1951-06_Gorgon776/page/n7/mode/2up

Comment: The site's colourscheme is garish only for the first page, after that it's just plain white on black and very nice on the eyes.